# Will Ouroboros Crypsinous be included in Ouroboros Omega?

Tags: proof-of-stake, ouroboros, privacy

Last year at the 2021 Cardano Summit, IOHK provided a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PF1SW7e137A) that overviews the Ouroboros family of protocols developed since 2016, the consensus enhancements and security features they provide, and how Ouroboros Omega will be the culmination of this research.

IOHK published a [paper](https://iohk.io/en/research/library/papers/ouroboros-crypsinousprivacy-preserving-proof-of-stake/) in 2019 on privacy-preserving proof of stake called Ouroboros Crypsinous. The aim of the research was to provide a formal treatment of how a private ledger (ie, private transactions and private balances) could be attained using zk-SNARKS in a proof-of-stake consensus mechanism. The research seems to be inspired by Zcash (then called Zerocash).

There hasn't really been any mention of progress or development of Ouroboros Crypsinous since. Does anyone know if this work will be included in Ouroboros Omega? If not, do you know the reason? Is there still regulatory uncertainty about the use of private ledgers in public blockchains?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no plan for IOG to implement Ouroboros Crypsinous

https://iohk-io.netlify.app/en/blog/posts/2022/06/03/from-classic-to-chronos-the-implementations-of-ouroboros-explained/